# Parsing with json.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

i'm trying to use javascript/json.parse to parse some information  in json.

here is an example code in which i am using it.

```
var jsontext = '{"place": Jamaica}';
var countries = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(countries.place);
```

That format does not work.

if i manually alter the json text to

```
var jsontext = '{"place": "Jamaica"}';
var countries = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(countries.place);
```

I get the result Jamaica which works. unfortunately the way i get the information does not have the quotation marks around Jamaica .

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k3V9p/

Comment: You cannot use JSON parsers for anything that's not valid JSON. You'll have to write your own parser.

Comment: Since you write a string, you can't put objects directly inside your JSON. (I assume Jamaica is an object you want in your array). But, what's the matter about writing json string in javascript to parse it later ? Why not creating a json object directly ?

Comment: @OlivierH - The purpose is creating a simple self-contained example, of course :)

Comment: @Craig, do you want to preserve some quote marks around Jamaica?

Comment: @Craig How do you get the info? Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this a lot how about a function to wrap the text in quotes.

```
function wrapInQuotes (str) {
    return '"' + str + '"';
}
```

If you need it inline:

```
(function (str) {return '"' + str + '"';}('string'));
```